# Android Studio Room - Como decirle a la app que si ya hay una bd creada, no la vuelva a crear y no truene mi app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room, room

tengo el siguiente código ejecutandose en mi MainActivity por cuestiones academicas:

```java
DbContext db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    DbContext.class,
                    "db"
            ).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
```

me gustaría pedirles su ayuda para decirle a mi app que si ya existe la base de datos, no la cree de nuevo o que la elimine y la vuelva a crear en su defecto, ya que al volver a abrir la app, esta se cierra sola y no es posible volver a ejecutarla. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: El logcat no me señala nada, solo me truena la app , lo unico que ví que me señaló era algo de UNIQUE en un campo código, pero según yo, es por que la BD se crea y al volver a abrir se trata de volver a crear, y truena. En ROOM no sé como se haga para evitar eso.

Comment: te recomiendo agregar ese mensaje donde señala "UNIQUE", probablemente estás tratando de realizar una restricción, por esta razon se cierra tu app.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es primero preguntar si existe una instancia y que la devuelva si existe o si no que ejecute ese código que tienes que crea la bd. [Aquí te dejo un ejemplo](https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942)

Comment: Si no te se;ala ningun error con alguna Entity debes saber que si haces cambios y no realizas migraciones debes eliminar por completo la BD antes de reinstalar el app. Ahopra bien si tu clase AppDatabase simplemente crea la BD agregale un validador a la instancia  del tipo if(INSTANCE == null) { Room.databaseBuilder...